# Mostrar max Precio,editor y nombre

Tags: mysql

Estoy empezando con el lenguaje SQL y tengo una pregunta

Tengo la siguiente tabla

```
create table JuegosSwitch(
id int(100) auto_increment,
nombre varchar(50),
editor varchar(50),
tipo varchar(50),
precio float(20),
Primary Key(id)
);
```

Y los siguientes datos

```
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Super Mario 3D World','Nintendo','Plataformas',44.45);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Persona 5 Strikers','Atlus','Action RPG',37.55);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Doom','Bethesda','Shooter',25.55);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Bayonetta','Platinum Games','Action RGP',1,'Juegos Switch',69.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Final Fantasy VII','Square Enix','JRGP',1,'Juegos Switch',19.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Mario Party','Nintendo','Party Games',1,'Juegos Switch',49.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'The Legenf of Zelda Breath of the Wild','Nintendo','Aventuras',1,'Juegos Switch',69.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'13 Sentinels Aegis Rim','Atlus','JRGP',1,'Juegos Switch',37.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Metroid Dread','Nintendo','JRGP',1,'Juegos Switch', 59.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'The Red Strings Club','DeconsctructTeam','Aventura',1,'Juegos Switch',14.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Skyrim','Bethesda','Aventura',1,'Juegos Switch',59.95);
insert into JuegosSwitch values (null,'Pepito','Albert Games','Aventura',1,'Juegos Switch',79.95);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es algo que seguramente sea muy simple pero no consigo…quiero hacer un select que me muestre el valor maximo de precio de videojuego por editor. Que me haga un listado de todas los editores, cual es el precio maximo de cada videojuego que tienen a la venta y como se llama ese titulo. Lo que si consigo es obtener el valor maximo de precio de cada editor

```
select editor,max(precio) from JuegosSwitch group by editor;
```

Pero si a este select le añado el nombre

```
select editor,max(precio),nombre from JuegosSwitch group by editor;
```

El nombre del videojuego que obtengo no es el del precio maximo, es el primero que encuentra de esa editora dentro de la tabla sin tener en cuenta el precio. Me gustaría saber como podria realizar algo asi.

Gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes encontrar el máximo en una subconsulta, de esta forma:

```
SELECT
    editor, nombre, precio
FROM
    JuegosSwitch j1
WHERE
    precio = (SELECT MAX(precio) FROM JuegosSwitch j2 WHERE j2.editor = j1.editor)
```

Te dejo un ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f884fe/1).

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 2):

No puedes visualizar campos ya agrupados en una consulta de agrupamiento. No te mostrará el que corresponda, sino el primero que encuentre. En cambio, sí que puedes realizar una combinación entre la tabla original y la subconsulta de máximos que has definido:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select editor,max(precio) precio
      from JuegosSwitch
      group by editor  
  ) c1 JOIN JuegosSwitch USING(editor,precio);
```

Así obtendrás todos los campos de esos registros que te interesan:

```
+------------------+--------+----+----------------------------------------+------------+
| editor           | precio | id | nombre                                 | tipo       |
+------------------+--------+----+----------------------------------------+------------+
| Platinum Games   |  69.95 |  4 | Bayonetta                              | Action RGP |
| Square Enix      |  19.95 |  5 | Final Fantasy VII                      | JRGP       |
| Nintendo         |  69.95 |  7 | The Legenf of Zelda Breath of the Wild | Aventuras  |
| Atlus            |  37.95 |  8 | 13 Sentinels Aegis Rim                 | JRGP       |
| DeconsctructTeam |  14.95 | 10 | The Red Strings Club                   | Aventura   |
| Bethesda         |  59.95 | 11 | Skyrim                                 | Aventura   |
| Albert Games     |  79.95 | 12 | Pepito                                 | Aventura   |
+------------------+--------+----+----------------------------------------+------------+
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!!!!!